# why is my binary update prints gibberish/garbage instead of the information that i have inserted?

Tags: c, file, binary

i'm trying to build a struct of a student that contain name,5 grades,and average. then i want to scan 5 students and write their info on a binary file and after that i want to update 1 of the students grade...

i guess the way that i call the function update or the way that i open the file is wrong...

hope you can help me..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define G 5
#define S 1
typedef struct {
    char name[N];
    int grade[G];
    double average;
}student;

double aver(int a[G]);
void scan_student(student *student);
void print_student(student *student);
void update_grades(FILE *info);


void scan_student(student *student)
{
    int j;
flushall();
   printf("Enter the student's name\n");
   gets(student->name);
     for(j=0;j<G;j++)
        {
          printf("Enter the student's grade number --> %d\n",j);
          scanf("%d",&student->grade[j]);
        }
    student->average=aver(student->grade);

}

void print_student(student *STUD)

{
    int j;
    printf("this is the details of the student: \n");
    puts(STUD->name);
    for (j=0;j<G;j++)
    {
        printf("grade number --> %d\n",j);
        printf("%d\n",STUD->grade[j]);
    }
    printf("this is %s's average:\t\n%lf\n",STUD->name,STUD->average);
}










double aver(int a[G])
{
    double AVER;
    int sum=0,i;
    for (i=0;i<G;i++)
        sum+=a[i];
    AVER=sum/G;
    return AVER;
}


void update_grades()
{
    int size,i,boolean=0;
    char st[N];
    FILE* info;
    student student;
    size=sizeof(student);
    info=fopen("My Grades.txt","rb");
    printf("Enter the name of the student that you want to change he's details...\n");
    flushall();
    gets(st);
    rewind(info);
    do{

    fseek(info,size,SEEK_CUR);
fread(&student,size,1,info);
if(strcmp(student.name,st))
{
    boolean=1;
    printf("this is the selected student\n");

    print_student(&student);

    printf("\n\n wich gread would you like to change? choose from 1 to 5 :\n");
    scanf("%d",i);
    printf("insert new grade:\n");
    scanf("%d",student.grade[i-1]);

    printf("this is the student details after the changes:\n\n");
    print_student(&student);
    fseek(info,(-1)*size,SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&student, size,1,info);
}
    }while((!feof(info))&&(!boolean));
if(!boolean)
    printf("\n\n there is no such student named %s....\n",st);
fclose(info);
}

void main()
{
int i,j,size;
char a;
student STUD;
FILE *txt;
txt=fopen("My Grades.txt","wb");
do{
size=sizeof(STUD);
scan_student(&STUD);
print_student(&STUD);
fwrite( &STUD,size,1,txt);
printf("would you like to add another student? Y/N\n");
    do{
        flushall();
    a=getchar();
    }while ((a!='Y')&&(a!='N'));
}while(a=='Y');

fclose(txt);
update_grades();
}
```

this is the error that i get...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pc9yz3a1w1cbcm1/example%20error.jpg

ok guys..so this is the fixed code.. but still same problem..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define G 5
#define S 1
typedef struct {
    char name[N];
    int grade[G];
    double average;
}student;


double aver(int a[G]);
void scan_student(student *student);
void print_student(student *student);
void update_grades(FILE *info);


void scan_student(student *st)
{
    int j;
flushall();
   printf("Enter the student's name\n");
   gets(st->name);
     for(j=0;j<G;j++)
        {
          printf("Enter the student's grade number --> %d\n",j);
          scanf("%d",&st->grade[j]);
        }
    st->average=aver(st->grade);

}

void print_student(student *STUD)

{
    int j;
    printf("this is the details of the student: \n");
    puts(STUD->name);
    for (j=0;j<G;j++)
    {
        printf("grade number --> %d\n",j);
        printf("%d\n",STUD->grade[j]);
    }
    printf("this is %s's average:\t\n%lf\n",STUD->name,STUD->average);
}










double aver(int a[G])
{
    double AVER,sum=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<G;i++)
        sum+=a[i];
    AVER=sum/G;
    return AVER;
}


void update_grades()
{
    int size,i,boolean=0;
    char st[N];
    FILE* info;
    student STUDENT;
    size=sizeof(student);
    info=fopen("My Grades.txt","rb");
    printf("Enter the name of the student that you want to change he's details...\n");
    flushall();
    gets(st);
    rewind(info);
    do{

    fseek(info,size,SEEK_CUR);
fread(&STUDENT,size,1,info);
if(strcmp(STUDENT.name,st))
{
    boolean=1;
    printf("this is the selected student\n");

    print_student(&STUDENT);

    printf("\n\n wich gread would you like to change? choose from 1 to 5 :\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("insert new grade:\n");
    scanf("%d",&STUDENT.grade[i-1]);

    printf("this is the student details after the changes:\n\n");
    print_student(&STUDENT);
    fseek(info,(-1)*size,SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&STUDENT, size,1,info);
}
    }while((!feof(info))&&(!boolean));
if(!boolean)
    printf("\n\n there is no such student named %s....\n",st);
fclose(info);
}


void main()
{
int i,j,size;
char a;
student STUD;
FILE *txt;
txt=fopen("My Grades.txt","wb");
do{
size=sizeof(STUD);
scan_student(&STUD);
print_student(&STUD);
fwrite( &STUD,size,1,txt);
printf("would you like to add another student? Y/N\n");
    do{
        flushall();
    a=getchar();
    }while ((a!='Y')&&(a!='N'));
}while(a=='Y');

fclose(txt);
update_grades();


}
```

ok so when i add only 1 student i get this error like in the link that i shared..
And if I scan more than one student .. And choose a student from the file  (not the first one)...
Then it updates the student that was before him on the list...

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name for a struct typedef and a variable.  It's probably "defined" as to what happens if you do this, but not one person in 100 could tell you for sure what that was.

Comment: You haven't said what problems you see.  Fixing compiler warnings will fix a couple of issues with `update_grades` however.  Also, `aver` rounds values down by performing integer arithmetic before converting to `double` in the line `AVER=sum/G;`.  Cast either `sum` or `G` to `double` to avoid this

Comment: My guess is that it's printing gibberish because you don't understand what it's doing.  I certainly can't figure it out, without about 15 minutes of study.  Clean up your notation -- clear names with no "sharing", clean up your formatting, add some *meaningful* comments about what you are doing and what you assume true at each major juncture, add some diagnostic printf statements, and work through the code slowly, checking each result.

Comment: I have changed the argument name and sum to double, thank you...

Comment: i uploaded a link that shows my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Error could be on declaring like this: `void scan_student(student *student);`. It could be `void scan_student(student *STUD);` Also change:

```
void scan_student(student *student)
{
...
}
```

as

```
void scan_student(student *STUD)
{...}
```

Comment: @simonc Does having same struct typename and pointer name as student creates problem?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  While it can make things confusing, it doesn't break the build.

Comment: i changed to "student" to something else... but still i got the same problem... looks like the problem was not there..

Comment: @GameISAI: If you have not solved the problem, could you upload the latest code in the Question?